# Computing the normal of a plane given 3 points

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have a plane in 3D space and I am trying to compute its normal vector. This is the strategy I'm using right now.

1) Choose any 3 points on the plane. $A, B, C$

2) Find line $AB = B - A$ and line $AC = C - A$

3) $\mathbf{n} = AB\times AC$

4) $\mathbf{\hat{n}} = \frac{1}{|\mathbf{n}|}\mathbf{n}$

I'm pretty sure I'm going wrong with step 1). because I know that the points on the plane must not be collinear. However, I'm not really sure what collinear means in the the context of a 3D plane.

EDIT: these are the 3 points I'm using

[image]

However, I sample the corresponding points after I hit the plane with a 4x4 matrix which represents an affine transform. Will these points no longer be collinear?

Comment: collinear means that $A,B,C$ are situated on one line

Comment: Note after edit: note that you can use cross product only for vectors in $R^3$. Are you dealing with that?

Comment: @gimusi yeah, pretend that the image I have pasted has all $z=0$. All data I am dealing with is 3D

Comment: "Will these points no longer be collinear?": hm, were they ever collinear ?

Comment: If your plane is known by its implicit equation $a+by+cz+d=0$, there is no need to sample any points. $\mathbb n=(a,b,c)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost perfectly correct but Step (1) should be replaced with

(1) Choose any 3 non-collinear points on the plane, A, B, C.

Collinear means on the same straight line. You would detect collinearity in Step (3) where the cross product would then yield the zero vector.

(However, I think you'd be unlucky if you picked 3 collinear points at random.)

Step (4) is only necessary if you require a unit vector.

After question Edit:

The points in the circles are not collinear. There is no single straight line that passes through all 3 points. If you want to know the effect of affine transformations on points then it sounds like it could be asked as a new question.

Comment: Thanks again. Regarding step(4), I want to plot the normal vector on a graphics program and would like to control its length (but have it point in the right direction). So, I normalized it, and then multiplied the normalized unit vector by some arbitrary number like 100 (pixels), but this caused the direction to change. How can I achieve the behavior I described?

Comment: @Carpetfizz multiplying a vector by a positive constant will not change its direction, only its magnitude. Multiplying by a negative constant will flip the direction. I think your plotting issue is really about the software you are using so you'd need to consult a manual or other source of help about that.

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely right for A,B,C not on the same line ( that is **not collinear**) since cross product $u\times v$ gives a vector orthogonal to the u-v plane.

Note also that you don’t need step 4 since $\vec n$ is just fine as normal vector (normalization is not necessary).

Finally observe that when we know the plane equation

$$ax+by+cz=d$$

a normal vector is $$\vec n=(a,b,c)$$

Comment: if cross product is $\neq 0$ of course they are not collinear